# How to print entire Twelve Days of Christmas lyrics without loops and if-else

Tags: python

As stated in the title, I tried many ways and the closest I got till was here:

```
lyrics = ['A partridge in a pear tree','Two turtle doves, and','Three 
French hens','Four colly birds','Five Gold Rings','Six geese a- 
laying','Seven swans a-swimming','Eights maids a-milking','Nine ladies 
dancing','Ten lords a-leaping','Elven piper piping','Twelve drummers 
drumming']
days = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth','Sixth','Seventh','Eighth','Nineth' 
,'Tenth','Eleventh','Twelveth']

x=1

def base():
     print("On the " + days[0] + " day of christmas my true love sent to me")
     print(lyrics[0]+"\n")

def day_of_christmas(x):
    try:
        print("On the " + days[x] + " day of christmas my true love sent to me")

        y = count_days(x)
        day_of_christmas(y)
    except IndexError:
        return None

def count_days(day):
    try:
        print(str(lyrics[day]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-1]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-2]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-3]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-4]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-5]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-6]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-7]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-8]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-9]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-10]))
        print(str(lyrics[day-11]+"\n"))
    except IndexError:
        return None
    return day+1

base()
day_of_christmas(x)
```

My output is:

```
On the first day of christmas my true love sent to me
A partridge in a pear tree

On the second day of christmas my true love sent to me
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
Twelve drummers drumming
Elven piper piping
Ten lords a-leaping
Nine ladies dancing
Eights maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five Gold Rings
Four colly birds
Three French hens

On the third day of christmas my true love sent to me
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
Twelve drummers drumming
Elven piper piping
Ten lords a-leaping
Nine ladies dancing
Eights maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five Gold Rings
Four colly birds

On the fourth day of christmas my true love sent to me
Four colly birds
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
Twelve drummers drumming
Elven piper piping
Ten lords a-leaping
Nine ladies dancing
Eights maids a-milking
Seven swans a-swimming
Six geese a-laying
Five Gold Rings
```

The output basically repeats itself(too long to display all) only the 12th day has correct output. I know I am forcing the 12 lines for each day and they are repeating due to the list negative index but I need to solve this problem **without** loops and if-else.

I expected the output(in this order till 12th day):

```
On the first day of christmas my true love sent to me
A partridge in a pear tree

On the second day of christmas my true love sent to me
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the third day of christmas my true love sent to me
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the fourth day of christmas my true love sent to me
Four colly birds
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
```

Comment: Why not just hard code and print the 12 days?

Comment: I see no way you can avoid a loop. Any reason why you don't prefer to loop?

Comment: You can avoid *loops*, as long as you mean "syntactic constructs like `for`" rather than "iteration itself".

Comment: Is this part 1 of an assignment, where you will next refactor your code to include loops and ifs as you progress through your assignments?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere its a class practice where to question was to write as little lines of code as possible without loops and if-else, and theres no part 2 of the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [corecursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) (fancy name for counting up from a staring point, rather than down to a base case), and catch the `IndexError` when you try to access `days[12]` in the call to `sing_day(12)` to stop.

```
def sing_day(n):

    # This line raises an IndexError when n == 12
    print("On the {} day of ...".format(days[n]))
    print("\n".join(lyrics[n::-1]))
    print()
    sing_day(n+1)  # Corecurse on the next day


def print_lyrics():
    try:
        sing_day(0)   # Start the song, and keep going as long as you can
    except IndexError:
        pass  # We got to sing_day(12), we can stop now.

print_lyrics()
```

Or, abuse `list(map(...))` for the side effect of calling `sing_day`:

```
def sing_day(n):
    print("On the ...")
    print("\n".join(...))
    print()

def print_lyrics():
    list(map(sing_day, range(12)))
```

Comment: This has to be the shortest answer! Thank you, I was stuck at this question for a while :D

Answer (score 2):

I like @cricket_007's solution, but you can do it recursively too. This is a bit silly:

```
lyrics = [
    ("first", "A partridge in a pear tree"),
    ("second", "Two turtle doves, and"),
    ("third", "Three French hens"),
    ("fourth", "Four colly birds"),
    ("fifth", "Five Gold Rings")
]

def get_lyrics_for_day(n):
    current_lyrics = [lyrics[n][1]]
    if n != 0:
        previous_lyrics = get_lyrics_for_day(n-1)
        current_lyrics.extend(previous_lyrics)
    return current_lyrics

def print_lyrics(iteration):
    if iteration == len(lyrics):
        return
    all_lyrics = get_lyrics_for_day(iteration)
    nth = lyrics[iteration][0]
    print("\n".join([f"On the {nth} day of christmas my true love sent to me"] + all_lyrics), end="\n\n")
    print_lyrics(iteration+1)

print_lyrics(0)
```

Output:

```
On the first day of christmas my true love sent to me
A partridge in a pear tree

On the second day of christmas my true love sent to me
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the third day of christmas my true love sent to me
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the fourth day of christmas my true love sent to me
Four colly birds
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree

On the fifth day of christmas my true love sent to me
Five Gold Rings
Four colly birds
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
```

Comment: You're using an `if` statement, which the question forbids.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question forbade if-else constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a sequence of functions like so:

```py
def the12th():
    print("On the twelfth day...")
    the11th()

def the11th():
   print("On the eleventh day...")
   the10th()
```

and so on. Then in your main, call them like this:

```py
the1st()
the2nd()
the3rd()
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A loop from 0-12 would be prefered, but you can use list-slicing to get the lyrics, then join them on a newline.

```
def twelve_days(day):
    print("On the {} day of christmas my true love sent to me".format(days[day]))
    print('\n'.join(reversed(lyrics[:day+1])))

twelve_days(0)
twelve_days(1)
twelve_days(2)
twelve_days(3)
```

Output

```
On the first day of christmas my true love sent to me
A partridge in a pear tree
On the second day of christmas my true love sent to me
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
On the third day of christmas my true love sent to me
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
On the fourth day of christmas my true love sent to me
Four colly birds
Three French hens
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree
```

Note that `day_of_christmas(y)` within `def day_of_christmas(x)` is somewhat a loop... but doing *recursion*

Comment: You'd have to reverse the lyrics slice to get the desired order.

Answer (score -1):

*Check out this*

```
def print_lyrics(count):
    print("On the " + days[count] + " day of christmas my true love sent to me")
    print('\n'.join(lyrics[:count + 1]), end="\n")
    print()
    count = count + 1
    if count < len(days):
        print_poem(count)

count = 0
print_lyrics(count)
```

Comment: You are using an `if` statement.